# Neo4j Cypher - Vary traversal depth conditional on number of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database (version 2.0.0) containing words and their etymological relationships with other words. I am currently able to create "word networks" by traversing these word origins, using a variable depth Cypher query.

For client-side performance reasons (these networks are visualized in JavaScript), and because the number of relationships varies significantly from one word to the next, I would like to be able to make the depth traversal conditional on the number of nodes. My query currently looks something like this:

```
start a=node(id)
match p=(a)-[r:ORIGIN_OF*1..5]-(b)
where not b-->()
return nodes(p)
```

Going to a depth of 5 usually yields very interesting results, but at times delivers far too many nodes for my client-side visualization to handle. I'd like to check against, for example, `sum(length(nodes(p)))` and decrement the depth if that result exceeds a particular maximum value. Or, of course, any other way of achieving this goal.

I have experimented with adding a `WHERE` clause to the path traversal, but this is specific to individual paths and does not allow me to `sum()` the total number of nodes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, have you considered simply using a "limit" on the number of nodes to return ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do isn't fairly straight forward in a single query. Assuming you are using labels and indexing on the word property, the following query should do what you want.

```
MATCH p=(a:Word { word: "Feet" })-[r:ORIGIN_OF*1..5]-(b)
WHERE NOT (b)-->()
WITH reduce(pathArr =[], word IN nodes(p)| pathArr + word.word) AS wordArr
MATCH (words:Word)
WHERE words.word IN wordArr
WITH DISTINCT words
MATCH (origin:Word { word: "Feet" })
MATCH p=shortestPath((words)-[*]-(origin))
WITH words, length(nodes(p)) AS distance
RETURN words
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 100
```

I should mention that this most likely won't scale to huge datasets. It will most likely take a few seconds to complete if there are 1000+ paths extending from your origin word.

The query basically does a radial distance operation by collecting all distinct nodes from your paths into a word array. Then it measures the shortest path distance from each distinct word to the origin word and orders by the closest distance and imposes a maximum limit of results, for example 100.

Give it a try and see how it performs in your dataset. Make sure to index on the word property and to apply the `Word` label to your applicable word nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's helped give me a better understanding of Cypher. I (sort of) got it to work, but as expected, the query is terribly slow on the nodes where the code is most needed. Because, in my case, it is fairly rare to get nodes with so many connections, would there be anything terribly wrong with simply re-querying the database if the response is too large? Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to understand more about your application requirements. There are so many ways to optimize your data model to enable performant querying capability. -- Re-querying the database would be fine if it provides the response time you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

what comes to my mind is an stupid optimalization of graph:

what you need to do is to ad an information into each node, which will show up how many connections it has for each depth from 1 to 5, ie:

```
start a=node(id)
match (a)-[r:ORIGIN_OF*1..1]-(b)
with count(*) as cnt
set a.reach1 = cnt

...

start a=node(id)
match (a)-[r:ORIGIN_OF*5..5]-(b)
where not b-->()
with count(*) as cnt
set a.reach5 = cnt
```

then, before each run of your question query above, check if the number of reachX < you_wished_results and run the query with `[r:ORIGIN_OF*X..X]`

this would have some consequences - either you would have to run this optimalisation each time after new items or updates happens to your db, or after each new node /updated node you must add the `reachX` param to the update